# Bind Class Method to Click Event via $.proxy()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read another post on here about this subject and I tried the solution (to use $.proxy()), but it doesn't work as expected in my code. It just executes as soon as the page is loaded and the click event doesn't fire when I click the element.

```
/**
 * menu-slider.js
 * Written by: Jay Simons
 * Cloudulus.Media (https://code.cloudulus.media)
 */
class menuSlider
{
    constructor(id, maxWidth)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.ele = $("#"+id);
        this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
        this.menuWidth = this.ele.width();
        this.winWidth = $(document).width();

        this.calc();
        $(window).resize(this.calc());
    }

    calc()
    {
        this.menuWidth = this.ele.width();
        this.winWidth = $(document).width();

        if (this.winWidth <= this.maxWidth)
        {
            this.ele.css("margin-right", -this.menuWidth+"px");
            this.ele.append('<div id="menu-slider-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>');
            $("#menu-slider-btn").css('position', 'absolute').css('top', 0).css('left', -$("#menu-slider-btn").width()+'px')
                .css("box-shadow", "none").css('color', 'white');
            $("#menu-slider-btn").click($.proxy(this.toggle(), this));
        }
    }

    toggle()
    {
        if(this.ele.css("margin-right") == -this.menuWidth+"px" && !this.ele.is(':animated'))
        {
            this.ele.show();
            this.ele.animate({"margin-right": '+='+this.menuWidth}).addClass("active");
        }
        else
        {
          if(!this.ele.is(':animated'))
          {
              this.ele.animate({"margin-right": '-='+this.menuWidth}).removeClass("active");
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *calling* the member functions and passing their return values instead of passing them to event handlers. Change these:

```
$(window).resize(this.calc());
$("#menu-slider-btn").click($.proxy(this.toggle(), this));
```

To these:

```
$(window).resize($.proxy(this.calc, this));
$("#menu-slider-btn").click($.proxy(this.toggle, this));
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling a function in `$.proxy()` by adding `()` on `this.toggle`. you have to write something like this.

```
$("#menu-slider-btn").click($.proxy(this.toggle, this));
```

I suggest you have to declare anonymous function in a variable like

```
/**
 * menu-slider.js
 * Written by: Jay Simons
 * Cloudulus.Media (https://code.cloudulus.media)
 */
class menuSlider
{
    constructor(id, maxWidth)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.ele = $("#"+id);
        this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
        this.menuWidth = this.ele.width();
        this.winWidth = $(document).width();
        this.calc();
        $(window).resize(this.calc);
    }

    this.calc = function(){        {
        this.menuWidth = this.ele.width();
        this.winWidth = $(document).width();

        if (this.winWidth <= this.maxWidth)
        {
            this.ele.css("margin-right", -this.menuWidth+"px");
            this.ele.append('<div id="menu-slider-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>');
            $("#menu-slider-btn").css('position', 'absolute').css('top', 0).css('left', -$("#menu-slider-btn").width()+'px')
                .css("box-shadow", "none").css('color', 'white');
            $("#menu-slider-btn").click($.proxy(this.toggle, this));
        }
    };

    this.toggle = function(){
        if(this.ele.css("margin-right") == -this.menuWidth+"px" && !this.ele.is(':animated'))
        {
            this.ele.show();
            this.ele.animate({"margin-right": '+='+this.menuWidth}).addClass("active");
        }
        else
        {
          if(!this.ele.is(':animated'))
          {
              this.ele.animate({"margin-right": '-='+this.menuWidth}).removeClass("active");
          }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think I understand now. I thought if I didn't have the () that JS would think I'm referring to a property and not a function, but I see that adding the () calls the function rather than referring to it. Am I correct?